# dummify a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on the same old death causes database with this structure:

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| decesso            | int(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| anno               | year(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| mese               | int(2)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| data               | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| age                | int(3)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sex                | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cod_comune         | int(6)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| nome_comune        | varchar(40)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| causa_fin          | varchar(4)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cod_tit            | varchar(3)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

in practice, every row is a death record, no matter the cause, the town, the age and stuff. In particular, the column `cod_tit` contains the code for the macro family of diseases, such as `I = cancer, II = heart diseases` and so on; this column is therefore composed like `I,I,IX,XX,...`

What I need is to have one column for every disease and values 0 if the guy died for another cause and 1 if he died for that very cause; something like a matrix like this

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| age | sex | town | dis_I | dis_II | dis_III|
+--------------------------------------------+
| 85  | M   | 0001 | 1     | 0      | 0      |
| 59  | M   | 0001 | 0     | 0      | 1      |
| 78  | F   | 0200 | 0     | 1      | 0      |
| 90  | M   | 0032 | 0     | 0      | 2      |
| ......                                     |
| and so on                                  |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

is that possible in mysql?

Comment: Yes it is. its called Pivoting table! There are tons of answered questions here! To your particular case you will need a procedure. Take a look here? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47902/how-to-transpose-convert-rows-as-columns-in-mysql

Comment: It's possible - but tedious when you have dozens of possible causes.

Comment: I don't guess you can do it if the number of diseases are not fixed, and even if you can, this is not actually the correct solution in a RDBMS. Instead you should use a diseases table with a foreign key in your deads table!

Comment: I didn't even know that pivoting a table on mysql was possible. My bad. For everybody, the macro categories of diseases, as WHO says, are 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT age,sex,town,
       CASE cod_tit WHEN 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS dis_I ,
       CASE cod_tit WHEN 'II' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS dis_II ,
...
FROM tableName
```

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.

Comment: It works; by doing this 1 row is still 1 case of that for any cause; if I also wanted to count the cases for every cause, where do I have to put `count`? I have just figured out that I don't have to put `count(cod_tit)` before case